# Rでのwebスクレイピングで、データが抽出できない

Tags: r, web-scraping

Rでwebスクレイピングを行っているのですが, 抽出したいデータが変数内に入りません.
抽出したいのは, テーブル型のデータです.
サイトは, 東京都教育委員会の都立高校検索のサイトで、アクセスのところの駅・路線・所要時間のデータを抽出したいと考えております.

使用したライブラリ：rvest
Rのバージョン：R 4.2.1
使用したOS：macOS

以下にコードを添付します.

```
library(rvest)

html <- read_html("https://www.kyoiku.metro.tokyo.lg.jp/static/high_school/index.html?", encoding= "UTF-8")
Sys.sleep(1)
tbl <- html_nodes(html, xpath="//*[id=hitList]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table")
```

この後, html_table()を用いたいと思ったのですが, 上記のtblの段階で, データが空になってしまいます.
tblにデータが入るようにするには、どのようにしたら良いでしょうか.
ご回答お待ちしております.

Comment: `[id=hitList]`の部分を`[@id='hitList']`にしてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: @kunif　kunifさん, ご回答ありがとうございます. ご指摘いただいたように, コードを変更して再度実行してみましたが, 同じ状態になってしまいます.

Comment: そうですか、Pythonとseleniumだったらそれで出来たのですが、Rではちょっと違うということでしょうか。こんな記事を見つけたので、XPATHの書き方そのものが違うのかもしれませんね。[スクレイピング：HTML編](https://shohei-doi.github.io/notes/posts/2019-04-21-scraping-html/) 記事の内容から類推すると試しに`//*[id=hitList]`の部分を`//div[@id = 'hitList']`にしてみるとか？

Comment: 指定している XPATH ノードは `JavaScript(XMLHttpRequest)` によって描画されています。通信内容を確認すると判るかと思いますが、XHR で`https://www.kyoiku.metro.tokyo.lg.jp/static/high_school/js/data.csv` を取得して、内容を加工して表示しています。

Comment: こんな記事 [JSで生成されるページをRSelenium +rvestでスクレイピング](https://qiita.com/saltcooky/items/e713f786a4f456117848), [Web scraping with R and rvest when javascript-rendered content in the web page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70954646/9014308) があったので、rvestというもの単独ではできないかもしれませんね。Python+Seleniumであればあまり工夫せずとも出来るでしょうが、Rでやりたいのだと思われますし。

Comment: お二方ともご回答いただきありがとうございます. JavaScriptで生成されているので, rvestのみでは, データを抽出できないということですね. RSeleniumを用いて再度試行してみて, もしダメそうであれば, Python+Seleniumを用いてやってみようと思います.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントにも書きましたが、ブラウザのデベロッパーツールで HTTP 通信の内容を確認してみると対象テーブルの中身(データ)は XMLHttpRequest によって取得されてレンダリングされています。具体的な URLは `https://www.kyoiku.metro.tokyo.lg.jp/static/high_school/js/data.csv` で、これを `read.csv()` でデータフレームに変換するとよいかと思います。(全197件のデータを一度で取得できます)

```r
> df <- read.csv("https://www.kyoiku.metro.tokyo.lg.jp/static/high_school/js/data.csv")

> nrow(df)
[1] 197
> head(colnames(df), 10)
 [1] "ファイル名"         "学校名"             "読み方"            
 [4] "住所"               "各校キャッチコピー" "アピールポイント"  
 [7] "スクールミッション" "使用路線"           "自転車通学可"      
[10] "バイク通学可"      

> head(df[c("学校名", "使用路線")])
           学校名
1     一橋高等学校
2   日比谷高等学校
3 晴海総合高等学校
4     三田高等学校
5   芝商業高等学校
6   六本木高等学校

使用路線
1 浅草橋駅（総武線、都営浅草線）　徒歩7分\n秋葉原駅（総武線、山手線、京浜東北線、日比谷線、つくばエクスプレス）　徒歩13分\n馬喰町駅（総武線）　徒歩3分\n馬喰横山駅（都営新宿線）　徒歩4分
2 永田町駅（有楽町線、半蔵門線、南北線）　徒歩8分\n赤坂見附駅（銀座線、丸ノ内線）　徒歩8分\n溜池山王駅（銀座線、南北線）　徒歩7分\n国会議事堂前駅（丸ノ内線、千代田線）　徒歩7分
3 東京メトロ有楽町線月島駅徒歩8分\n都営地下鉄大江戸線月島駅徒歩8分\n都営バス門33系統　亀戸駅前発　豊海水産埠頭行　月島三丁目下車　徒歩6分\n都営バス東15系統　深川車庫前発　東京駅八重洲口行　晴海一丁目下車　徒歩1分\n都営バス業10系統　新橋発　東京スカイツリー駅前行　晴海一丁目下車　徒歩0分
4 赤羽橋駅（都営大江戸線）　徒歩5分\n芝公園駅（都営三田線）　徒歩7分\n麻布十番駅（南北線）　徒歩10分\n三田駅（都営浅草線）　徒歩12分\n田町駅（山手線、京浜東北線）　徒歩13分
5 浜松町駅（山手線、京浜東北線）　徒歩5分\nモノレール浜松町駅（東京モノレール）　徒歩5分\n大門駅（都営浅草線、都営大江戸線）　徒歩5分\n竹芝駅（ゆりかもめ）　徒歩5分
6 麻布十番駅（都営大江戸線）　徒歩8分\n麻布十番駅（南北線）　徒歩9分\n六本木駅（日比谷線）　徒歩7分
```

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございました. 無事欲しいデータを手に入れることができました. ご協力いただきありがとうございました.

Answer (score 0):

[rsDriver {RSelenium}](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/RSelenium/html/rsDriver.html) を参照して作った記述例を下記に示します。

- ブラウザは Chrome が第一選択ですが最新版が非対応エラーになったので Firefox を使いました。
- 最初はトラブルが分かり易いように `verbose=TRUE` をお勧めします。特に初回はダウンロード等をして環境を構築しているようで少し時間がかかります。
- 試した環境は「macOS(M1) 13.5.2, R 4.3.1, RSelenium 1.7.9, rvest 1.0.3」です。

なお，今回は初期画面の20件を取得できましたが，全197件を取得するならなんらかの工夫が必要です。もっと良い方法もありそうですが，検索条件（`url` の末尾に `?q=23` 等で設定可）を変えて複数回に分けて取得する（最大表示件数は40件？）くらいしか思いつきませんでした。

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.kyoiku.metro.tokyo.lg.jp/static/high_school/index.html"

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", verbose=FALSE)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url)
src <- remDr$getPageSource()
remDr$close()
rD[["server"]]$stop()
## [1] TRUE

hs_html <- read_html(src[[1]])
## xml2::write_html(hs_html, "high_school.html")

school <- hs_html |>
    html_elements(".hitItemHead") |>
    html_elements("a") |>
    html_text()

access <- hs_html |>
    html_elements(".hitItemBody") |>
    html_elements("table > tbody > tr:nth_child(4) > td") |>
    html_text2()

tbl <- tibble(school, access)
print(tbl, width=74)
## # A tibble: 20 × 2
##    school           access                                                
##    <chr>            <chr>                                                 
##  1 一橋高等学校     "浅草橋駅（総武線、都営浅草線）　徒歩7分\n秋葉原駅（… 
##  2 日比谷高等学校   "永田町駅（有楽町線、半蔵門線、南北線）　徒歩8分\n赤… 
##  3 晴海総合高等学校 "東京メトロ有楽町線月島駅徒歩8分\n都営地下鉄大江戸線… 
##  4 三田高等学校     "赤羽橋駅（都営大江戸線）　徒歩5分\n芝公園駅（都営三… 
##  5 芝商業高等学校   "浜松町駅（山手線、京浜東北線）　徒歩5分\nモノレール… 
##  6 六本木高等学校   "麻布十番駅（都営大江戸線）　徒歩8分\n麻布十番駅（南… 
##  7 新宿高等学校     "新宿駅（山手線、総武線、中央線、埼京線、湘南新宿ライ…
##  8 新宿山吹高等学校 "江戸川橋駅（有楽町線）　徒歩10分\n早稲田駅（東西線）…
##  9 戸山高等学校     "西早稲田駅（副都心線）　徒歩1分\n高田馬場駅（山手線… 
## 10 総合芸術高等学校 "曙橋駅（都営新宿線）　徒歩9分\n新宿御苑前駅（丸の内… 
## 11 竹早高等学校     "茗荷谷駅（丸ノ内線）　徒歩10分\n茗荷谷駅（丸ノ内線）…
## 12 向丘高等学校     "白山駅（都営三田線）　徒歩7分\n本駒込駅（南北線）　… 
## 13 工芸高等学校     "水道橋駅（総武線）　徒歩2分\n水道橋駅（都営三田線）… 
## 14 浅草高等学校     "浅草駅（東武スカイツリーライン、銀座線、都営浅草線）…
## 15 上野高等学校     "根津駅（千代田線）　徒歩6分\n上野駅（山手線・京浜東… 
## 16 忍岡高等学校     "浅草橋駅（JR総武線、都営浅草線）　徒歩5分\n新御徒町… 
## 17 白鷗高等学校     "新御徒町駅（都営大江戸線、つくばエクスプレス）　徒歩…
## 18 蔵前工科高等学校 "浅草橋駅（総武線，都営浅草線）　徒歩10分\n蔵前駅（都…
## 19 墨田川高等学校   "東向島駅（東武スカイツリーライン）　徒歩6分\n曳舟駅… 
## 20 日本橋高等学校   "曳舟駅（東武伊勢崎線、東武亀戸線）　徒歩10分\n京成曳…
```

（御参考）
ページ下端の「さらに表示」を必要回数クリックしてからソースを取得することで，全197件を取得できるようです。

```
## ...

remDr$navigate(url)

for (i in 1:9) {
    Sys.sleep(1)
    moreDisp <- remDr$findElement(using="link text", "さらに表示")
    moreDisp$clickElement()
}

src <- remDr$getPageSource()

## ...

print(tbl, width=74)
## # A tibble: 197 × 2
##   school           access                                                 
##   <chr>            <chr>                                                  
## 1 一橋高等学校     "浅草橋駅（総武線、都営浅草線）　徒歩7分\n秋葉原駅（総…
## 2 日比谷高等学校   "永田町駅（有楽町線、半蔵門線、南北線）　徒歩8分\n赤坂…
## 3 晴海総合高等学校 "東京メトロ有楽町線月島駅徒歩8分\n都営地下鉄大江戸線月…
## 4 三田高等学校     "赤羽橋駅（都営大江戸線）　徒歩5分\n芝公園駅（都営三田…
## 5 芝商業高等学校   "浜松町駅（山手線、京浜東北線）　徒歩5分\nモノレール浜…
## 6 六本木高等学校   "麻布十番駅（都営大江戸線）　徒歩8分\n麻布十番駅（南北…
## # ℹ 191 more rows
```

Comment: ご返信が遅くなり申し訳ございません. 上記のコードをもとにコードを構築して, 無事データを取ることができました. ご協力いただき, ありがとうございました.